# Fit svg into a container

Tags: html, css, svg

I have this linkedin logo as svg that I'm trying to fit into a div element. However, the svg won't scale correctly. The logo is square, so I have set the viewBox to be 100x100 and also given the width and the height as 100. The result is that the logo is cropped: only one corner is shown. Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

```css
#container {
  height: 100px;
  width: 400px;
  background-color: rebeccapurple;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <svg width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
                    <path d="m 1227.06,212.93 h -213.44 v 334.187 c 0,79.731 -1.46,182.235 -110.983,182.235 -111.145,0 -128.164,-86.825 -128.164,-176.461 V 212.93 H 561.047 V 900.137 H 765.93 v -93.891 h 2.84 c 28.496,54.027 98.171,110.996 202.082,110.996 216.278,0 256.208,-142.336 256.208,-327.359 z M 320.344,994.082 c -68.457,0 -123.867,55.508 -123.867,123.868 0,68.3 55.41,123.8 123.867,123.8 68.277,0 123.765,-55.5 123.765,-123.8 0,-68.36 -55.488,-123.868 -123.765,-123.868 z M 427.09,212.93 H 213.496 V 900.137 H 427.09 Z M 1333.43,1440 H 106.289 C 47.6484,1440 0,1393.52 0,1336.21 V 103.91 C 0,46.5508 47.6484,0 106.289,0 H 1333.43 c 58.74,0 106.59,46.5508 106.59,103.91 v 1232.3 c 0,57.31 -47.85,103.79 -106.59,103.79" />
                </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: The path is bigger than 100 x 100 so it overflows the viewBox. Make the viewBox bigger if you want to see the whole path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since, your `coordinates vary in between -1500 to +1500`, you should make that or `similar coordinates as your viewport` (*the reason being all your points are included in the viewport area*) and then resize it using width and height as 100px.

**Here's a demonstration:**

```css
#container {
  height: 100px;
  width: 400px;
  background-color: rebeccapurple;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <svg width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 1500 1500">
                    <path d="m 1227.06,212.93 h -213.44 v 334.187 c 0,79.731 -1.46,182.235 -110.983,182.235 -111.145,0 -128.164,-86.825 -128.164,-176.461 V 212.93 H 561.047 V 900.137 H 765.93 v -93.891 h 2.84 c 28.496,54.027 98.171,110.996 202.082,110.996 216.278,0 256.208,-142.336 256.208,-327.359 z M 320.344,994.082 c -68.457,0 -123.867,55.508 -123.867,123.868 0,68.3 55.41,123.8 123.867,123.8 68.277,0 123.765,-55.5 123.765,-123.8 0,-68.36 -55.488,-123.868 -123.765,-123.868 z M 427.09,212.93 H 213.496 V 900.137 H 427.09 Z M 1333.43,1440 H 106.289 C 47.6484,1440 0,1393.52 0,1336.21 V 103.91 C 0,46.5508 47.6484,0 106.289,0 H 1333.43 c 58.74,0 106.59,46.5508 106.59,103.91 v 1232.3 c 0,57.31 -47.85,103.79 -106.59,103.79" />
                </svg>
</div>
```